# Python, sockets - What does this error mean?

Tags: python, sockets

So Im working on a simple socket chat in python and I keep getting this error when i run this code in PyCharm. There are no visible errors in the editor. In the tutorial an int is used as port and string as ip but it doesnt work for me. It says

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
 self.run()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
 self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
 TypeError: recv_loop() argument after * must be a sequence, not int.
```

Here is my code below

```
import socket
import threading
import os

connection = True


def send_loop(host, port2):  # Thread 1!
    s.connect((host, port2))
    while connection:
        msg = raw_input(":")
        if msg == "/quit":
            connection = False
        s.send(msg.encode("ascii"))
    s.send("Connection closed".encode("ascii"))
    s.close()
    return


def recv_loop():  # Thread 2!
    ip = "192.168.1.7"
    s.bind((ip, 12))
    s.listen(1)
    client, addr = s.accept()
    print "connected with : " + addr

    while connection:
        var = client.recv(1024)
        print var.decode("ascii")
    print "Connection closed"
    s.close()
    return


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

############    User Input  #############

port = int(raw_input("12/13:"))
if port == 12:
    t = threading.Thread(target=recv_loop, args=(12))
elif port == 13:
    t = threading.Thread(target=recv_loop(), args=(13))
else:
    print "ERROR CODE 01"
t.start()

ip = raw_input("others ip:")
os.system("cls")

port2 = 0

if port == 12:
    port2 = 13
elif port == 13:
    port2 = 12
else:
    print "ERROR CODE 2"

send_loop(ip, port2)
```

Comment: Spot the differences: `t = threading.Thread(target=recv_loop, args=(12))` vs. `t = threading.Thread(target=recv_loop(), args=(13))`... Also, note that a one-element tuple must be e.g. `(13,)`, not `(13)`.